# How to set maximum characters per line for text view in android

Tags: android

Hiii all,
this may be a possible duplicate but I couldn't find solution for my problem.I need to limit the number of characters per line when displaying on the textview and display the remaining characters in the next line.I cannot set ems value and I also tried setting maxLength attribute in xml but it is not displaying the remaining characters,Can any one tell me how can I do it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using

```
android:maxWidth="size"
```

Replace the "size" with the size you prefer. For example, `100dip`.

Comment: doesn't work if layout_width is set to wrap_content?

Answer (score 3):

Use this 
`android:maxLength="10"`

For more Information refer [this site](http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/01/numeric-edittext-and-edittext-with-max.html)

Answer (score 2):

use `android:maxWidth="10dip"` to limit the size of the textview.
With this limitation the next line (assume you used `setSingleLine(false)`) will start right after the `10dip`.

Using `android:maxLength="50"` for example would limit your textview, but doesn't ensure that it breaks after X characters

Answer (score 1):

Set these parameters of TextView:

```
android:layout_width="110dip"
android:singleline="false"
```

Experiment with the value of `android:layout_width` to find the value that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

use ConstraintLayout and android:layout_width="0dp". The text will adapt to the constraints

Answer (score -3):

Use this code:

```
android:maxLines="5"
android:maxLength="10"
```

Five line with max length of 10 character.

Comment: This adds nothing to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10933498/525478, which is more complete and over 2 years old...