# How to limit chars of each line in multiline edit text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to limit the char per line to 15 chars. After every 15 chars I should include/add a "enter" key pressed ("\n") to the line so that the user can write without stopping. Any suggestion?

This is my `EditText` xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

This is my ET `TextChangedListener`

```
ET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (count % 20 == 0)
            {
                ((Editable) s).append("\n");
                ET.setSelection(ET.getText().length());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why dont you write this programmatically? When it reaches 15 chars then change line

Comment: @lantonis because it doesn't change. It includes the "\n", but even when trying to move the cursor to the end  it stays at the end of that line

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933412/how-to-set-maximum-characters-per-line-for-text-view-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom `Text Watcher` here, please take help from the following template:

```
private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
private EditText recieved_et;

public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e) {
    recieved_et = e;
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
       //Your Implementation
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int count) 
{
    if (count % 20 == 0)
    {
        ((Editable) s).append("\n");
        recieved_et.setText(s.toString());
    }
}   

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       //Your Implementation
    }
}
```

Here is how you set this to your `Edit Text` :

`ET.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(ET));` 
I hope this helps.

Comment: That's not working, it will limit my entire length to 20, not the line to 20.

Comment: I didn't understand you. You only want to show some of your Lines to 20 chars ?

Comment: No, I want to limit each line to 20 chars, not the length of the full text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `TextWatcher` to the `EditText` programatically.

In the `onTextChanged()` function you can get the text and if the last line is 20 chars long, use `s.append("\n");` function.

You also need to implement the delete functionality I think. If the user deletes a `"\n"` char you also need to delete the previous one.

You also need to be careful about that function because it can easily stuck in an `infinite loop`.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried before, but even after including `ET.setSelection(ET.getText().length());` the cursor don't move to the next line

Comment: Can you post the code. I think there is no other way. We can go after your implementation.

Comment: I did not try it but can you try this: 
                ET.append("\n");
                ET.setSelection(ET.getText().length());

Comment: Tried that one too, but I got the same result. The cursor looks to be in the new line, but when I type any other letter it keeps writing in the previous line.

Comment: Ok I got it now. count variable is not the length of the text. you should go like this: if (s.length() % 20 == 0)

Comment: No, I got the same results.