# How make each line of TextView has same Length?

Tags: android

TextView has bad layout when dot or comma at end of line,I find AlignTextView in NET,it has algin layout and cleaner,but the problem is dot or comma can locate at start of line,
[image: Example]

comma cant at start of line ,it my want.
first use stackoverflow,sorry for my bad English......I really hope you can understand what i said...

Comment: seems to be a case of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933412/how-to-set-maximum-characters-per-line-for-text-view-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use this Justified Lib for your TextView

https://github.com/navabi/JustifiedTextView

https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android

Comment: Welcome keep coding, accept my answer for others help